# Are short expiration and lack of warranty disadvantages of cPanel's AutoSSL?

Tags: seo, https, security-certificate, openssl

I am trying to make my site HTTPS due to SEO and integration support with websites such as facebook.  For this, I need to purchase an SSL certificate. But I saw control panel & WHM gives me option to have free SSL certificate (AutoSSL), issued by cPanel, Inc. Certification Authority.

Now, I have to decide whether to use the free SSL (AutoSSL) or use a paid certificate.

One major difference I could see is that AutoSSL have shorter validity where as paid one can have more validity. I don't think this is an issue, as the free SSL auto renews near expiry. As i understand, same encryption is provided by both AutoSSL and paid SSL. But AutoSSL may not have warranty, which I don't feel as an issue.

As my intention is just to make one website secure using https, primarily for SEO and integration with websites like facebook, I believe AutoSSL is fine for me as it saves money.

Is my understanding wrong or any negatives in using AutoSSL over paid SSL?

Note: mine is not something like an ecommerce website where Organisation Validation and Extended Validation may be desired which paid ssl may only offer. I am ok with domain validation which AutoSSL offers.

Comment: "Now, I have to decide whether to use the free SSL (AutoSSL) or use a paid certificate." Your options are wider than that. Let's Encript is a valid global Certificate Authority and its provides certificates for free. There are others also. And "AutoSSL" may just be a reseller of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this depends on what is going on the website along with your ability to implement the solution, also whether you have subdomains.

Gauging by your question, you seem to have the ability to do any of the solutions.

Your websites content. I would suggest using a paid SSL if you are an e-commerce site or is a multi-site. Mainly due to the warranty and it allows you to add branding to the certificate. There is another factor of having an extended period for which you can keep the SSL. Most people won't look into the company too much if you're already successful with a bountiful amount of glowing reviews, if thats not the case - this may also help your credibility slightly.

Free SSL created through a Certificate Authority (CA) such as Let's Encrypt, is good for sites that are more informative than sensitive information (sites you're not requesting credit card information on). Along with not having the option to AutoSSL.

So your options would be to create your own through a CA. Where you upload a file to your server validating ownership, then you can get the keys required to pop into your cPanel.

Second option would be to use AutoSSL. It basically does it for you. If I have the option to do this and it is not a sensitive website, I would just choose this over Free CA SSL Certificate pretty much just for the simplicity.

Lastly to purchase an SSL or a WildcardSSL(for validating subdomains).

Depends on the server, website content, ability to implement each solution.

Any more questions pop them down, Jason.

Comment: Glad I could help out, feel free to request help installing! Happy safe browsing!

Comment: " Let's Encrypt, is good for sites that are more informative than sensitive information" I feel that to be highly subjective and not backed by any factual technical arguments (all certificates work at the end exactly in the same way). Also as for the guarantee part sold by some CAs, often as argument while their certificates are "better", AFAIK that was never actioned by anyone for any case and some doubts it would be actionable anyway the way they are written.

Comment: Also I am not sure to undertand, but I may have read things incorrectly, of the relationship you seem to draw between the certificate validity length and the website credibility.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek but they don’t work at the same level. Paid SSL certificates don’t just validate the domain (DV), it is also paired with Organisation Validation (OV) and Extended Validation (EV) - of which you cannot get with Let’s Encrypt. Your second comment is drawing attention to only the second part of what I was speaking about Paid SSL’s. I am saying all of these factors the DV, OV, EV, multisite cover & being able to brand your certificate will all ‘slightly’ improve your sites credibility.

Comment: You are now speaking about something else (that is not in your answer), how the validation works. Which is completely separate from the validity length for example (EV certificates are required to be more limited in length than others for example). This is a completely separate subject. Which is itself partially subjective, for example multiple people believe EV are not worthwhile anymore, starting from the fact that browsers vendor stopped showing it differently, or that very few companies in fact uses EV certificates in the wild.

Comment: What is "multisite" cover? You can get wildcard certificates or certificates with multiple names (related or not), from Let's Encrypt also, so no differences with any other CA....

Comment: "will all ‘slightly’ improve your sites credibility" this is still highly subjective and not backed by any kind of reference...

Comment: "but they don’t work at the same level." YES they work EXACTLY the same once being issued. The level of encryption is exactly the same. You are speaking about the validation, that is prior to the issuance. Once issued, they are the same, the only thing that can change is how clients display them or handle them if they like to discriminate. But under that, the TLS handshake is exactly the same.

Comment: Of course it’s subjective, the sites will all be secured in the same way by encrypting visitors connections to your site. Improving both the security of your site and the user. Your claim about multiple people thinking it’s not worth having an EV - that’s fine, again subjective. An extended warranty suggests you plan to be around for a while. Having an OV suggests you’re company is indeed who it says it is. Both slightly improving credibility (not security). I was unaware you can create a wildcard certificate through a CA like Let’s Encrypt so thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Referring back to the question, he isn’t contemplating the encryption ‘As I understand, same encryption is provided by both AutoSSL and paid SSL’. I am simply informing him about all the factors as to why people pay.

Comment: "Your claim about multiple people thinking it’s not worth having an EV - that’s fine, again subjective." Feel free to provide recent examples (your answer generally lacks any source/reference) of people claiming that EV is good/useful (besides articles coming from CAs of course).  As for the opposite there are many, among which: https://www.troyhunt.com/extended-validation-certificates-are-dead/  It is subjective indeed but there are some facts in it: browsers do not treat them differently, even big companies do not use them, lack of wildcards (for business reasons, not technical ones), etc.

Comment: As for warranties/insurances, one should take time to read: https://scotthelme.co.uk/do-ssl-warranties-protect-you-as-much-as-rocks-keep-tigers-away/  again, subjective, but with some real facts.

Comment: More on the "plus" side, but from a CA, this just landed: https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/digicert-leads-initiative-to-enhance-ev-ssl-certificates/ TL;DR: "In collaboration with several other certificate authorities, DigiCert has proposed 4 enhancements to the EV SSL validation processes: 1. Enforce Validation Level via CAA Records 2. Include LEI Data in SSL Certificates 3. Standardize Data Sources for EV Validation 4. Include Trademark Verification During EV Validation" All points however could apply as well for OV certificates. As the article states at the end, the problem is browser UI.

Comment: On EV one may want to read https://nooshu.github.io/blog/2020/01/26/the-impact-of-ssl-certificate-revocation-on-web-performance/ also as it has a specific section about them regarding their specific consequences at website loading time (that is the mandatory use of OCSP and hence the performance problems of it) "So the fact that by choosing a certain type of certificate will force the most popular browser on the planet to encounter these performance issues, we should examine why you’d choose to use one."

Comment: One interesting recent study at https://baymard.com/blog/perceived-security-of-payment-form on user perception of security during checkout. About seals: "Similar to the 2013 and 2016 results, it’s interesting to see that the majority of the most trusted seals are “trust seals”, not SSL seals. [..] Again, this just re-emphasizes that actual technical security is beyond most users’ understanding, and that users will go with what makes them feel most secure." YMMV